# how to see which line in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

How to print which line is the execution in gdb ?

For example, I use `b 1` to set a breakpoint at line 1, and then press `n` (or `step`) to execute next line (or function). Sometimes I loose track of which line am I in.

How can I see which line will be executed if I press `n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `frame` command to display a summary of the current frame, which includes the current line.